# Strings not being centered when printing

Tags: python

I am making something for my girlfriend, but there's a problem: the text is not being centered!

main.py:

```py
from zari import Zari

attributes = [a for a in vars(Zari) if not a.startswith('__')]
for attribute in attributes:
  print(attribute, "=".center(5), getattr(Zari, attribute))
```

prints

```
love   =   999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
smarts   =   9 <-- the issue is on this line 
looks   =   99999999999999999999999999
humor   =   99999999999
```

The equals sign isn't aligned with the others...

How do I do this?

Comment: I see no issue.  `'='.center(5)` gives `'  =  '`. Arguments to print are by default printed witha separator of `' '`.  So the result is `attribute + ' ' + '  =  ' + ' ' + getattr(Zari, attribute))`. That means between the first and last items you get `' ' + '  =  ' + ' ' ` or `'   =   '` or space space space equals space space space.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I meant visually when everything is printed out, the equals sign is not aligned with the others.

Comment: Pad the first item to the correct width and everything will align.  The simplest change to your code would be `print(attribute.ljust(6), "=", getattr(Zari, attribute))`.  See my answer for a better way of handling the justification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were expecting by centering just the equals sign, but assuming you want to align the equals sign vertically you can do as follows.

Given

```
arr = [('love', 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999),
       ('smarts', 9),
       ('looks', 99999999999999999999999999),
       ('humor', 99999999999)]
```

You could left justify the first column with

```
for x, y in arr:
    print(f'{x:<6} = {y}')
```

giving

```
love   = 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
smarts = 9
looks  = 99999999999999999999999999
humor  = 99999999999
```

or right justify with

```
for x, y in arr:
    print(f'{x:>6} = {y}')
```

giving

```
  love = 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
smarts = 9
 looks = 99999999999999999999999999
 humor = 99999999999
```

Comment: How do I change the padding based on the longest first element in the list of tuples?